# How to iterate over MultivaluedMap using forEach and a lambda expression

Tags: java, foreach, lambda, java-8

Java 8 allows iteration over a `Map` using `forEach` and a lambda expression as follows:

```
myMap.forEach((k, v)->{ System.out.println("Key: " + k + " Value: " + v); });
```

Is it possible to iterate over a `MultivaluedMap` using `forEach` and a lambda expression?

**UDPATE**

How do I call `foo` with 2 `String` parameters for a `MultivaluedMap<String, String>`?

```
myMultiMap.forEach((k, v)->{ foo(k, v); });
```

Comment: `myMultiMap.forEach((k, l) -> l.forEach( v -> foo(k, v)));`

Answer (score 6):

The interface [`MultivaluedMap<K, V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html) extends the [`Map<K,List<V>>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)  interface, therefore, there is `forEach` method and that is possible to use it.

```
new MultivaluedHashMap<String, String>()
        .forEach((String key, List<String> list)-> { ... });
```

I don't know what your `foo` method does, but I suggest* considering my point about that:

```
public <K, V> void foo(K key, V... values) { ... }
```

In such case, you needn't write inner `forEach` inside the lambda.
*(*it is wrong as explained @Holder in the comments*)

So, there is the only one proper way:

```
map.forEach((k, l) -> l.forEach( v -> foo(k, v)));
```

Comment: @ksl, yes it does, moreover, it has a couple of convenient methods to work on (such as `addAll(K key, V... newValues)`, `getFirst(K key)`)

Comment: I’d like to see the complete solution for invoking a `foo` method with varargs from the multi-map. Considering the standard Java 8 Collection API, you would have to convert the list to an array for each mapping. Maybe there’s another trick I missed so far…

Comment: In case you are wondering about the double `[[ … ]]` in the output: This only looks like doing the right thing, due to the nonsensical type parameters `<K, V>` on `foo`. So `V` is inferred as `List<String>` and each list is passed as first argument of the varargs parameter, which you print like being wrapped into another list. You could even invoke `foo` when it wasn’t a varargs method, as long as `V` can be anything the caller provides. But the OP wants to invoke a method processing `String`s…

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Andrew Tobilko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37832276/820657) I was able to figure out exactly what I want.

It can be done in one line as follows:

```
myMultiMap.forEach((k, v)->{ v.forEach(item-> foo(k, item)); });
```

Comment: you may avoid the inner `forEach` in the lambda, look at my  answer)

Comment: I can't change `foo` in my application. It takes two `String`s.